# Populate specific cells to the last row in another Sheet in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

it paste the value but not to the last rows in the sheet (List) the END(xlDown).offset(1) stop the 
macros and make it crash, I get error 1004 object undefined.

Can someone help me better up this code>

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Worksheets("FORM").Range("B7").Copy
Worksheets("List").Range("B7").End(xlDown).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("FORM").Range("D7").Copy
Worksheets("List").Range("C7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("FORM").Range("G7").Copy
Worksheets("List").Range("D7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'second line in the same row'
Worksheets("FORM").Range("A8").Copy
Worksheets("List").Range("F7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("FORM").Range("E8").Copy
Worksheets("List").Range("G7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("FORM").Range("H8").Copy
Worksheets("List").Range("H7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("FORM").Range("K8").Copy
Worksheets("List").Range("I7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the last row.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using `Worksheets("FORM")` when you should be using `Sheets("FORM")`
Also, when you're using `.Offset()` you need to specify the row AND column numbers you want to ofset by - so `.Offset(1,0)` in your case I imagine.
If you make those changes, your code should work.

Comment: I did, but I get this " Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Yes, but there's a tick button to accept an answer if it has worked for you - different to the up and down arrows.